# PySpark dataframe - change type to ObjectId

Tags: mongodb, casting, pyspark, objectid

I am writing to MongoDB with Pyspark using spark-mongo connector.
I want to edit some documents with this command

```
df.write.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").options(uri=uri, collection="test").mode("append").save()
```

df has a column '_id' but when I run that then I get two documents in MongoDB with the same _id, one with type 'String' and the other one with type 'ObjectId'. Is there a way to change the type of the column _id in my dataframe ? I found that the type should be StructType: { oid: String } but I don't know how to change that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is that I actually had some documents with _id string and others with _id ObjectId in my collection so when I was loading it with Spark it was inferring that the type of this field was string.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to force type on your dataframe.

Try to use a specific schema on creating it. 
[SQLContext - CreateDataFrame](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.SQLContext.createDataFrame)

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
schema = StructType([
    StructField('_id', StringType(), True),
    StructField('published', StringType(), True),
    ...
])
...
df =sql_context.createDataFrame(json_events, schema=schema)
```